# How can I add reply to comments in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I have the following code for getting comments and rendering a comment form. But I do not see any replies to a comment. I have searched the net but I am still unable to figure out what function to use and where to use it.

This is the code to render the form:

```
$comments_args = array(
    'fields' =>  $fields,
    'comment_field' => "<div class=\"comment-component\"><textarea name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" ></textarea></div>",
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Comment on this post!',
    'title_reply_to' => 'Reply to this comment',
    'label_submit' => 'Comment',
    'comment_notes_before' => "<p class='simple-title'>" . 'We will not publish you email' . ' '
);

comment_form($comments_args);
```

And this is the function which renders all comments and associated data:

```
function behdis_comment($comment_storage, $arguments = array('author' => true, 'date' => true,'id' => true,
'content' => true,'thumb' => true, 'class_name_main' => 'post-each-comment', 'class_name_meta' => 'post-each-comment-meta'))
{



    /** First we have to check for the argument. **/    

    // bc = behdisComment
    $bc_author = $arguments['author'];
    $bc_date = $arguments['author'];
    $bc_id = $arguments['author'];
    $bc_content = $arguments['author'];
    $bc_thumb = $arguments['author'];
    $bc_container_class = $arguments['class_name_main'];
    $bc_meta_class = $arguments['class_name_meta'];         

    // cont = container
    // main wrapper for each induvidual comment
    $cont_main_opening = "<div class=\"$bc_container_class\">";
    $div_closing = "</div>";
    // end of main wrapper

    // main wrapper for each induvidual comment
    $cont_main_opening = "<div class=\"$bc_container_class\">";
    // end of main wrapper

    $cont_meta_opening = "<div class=\"$bc_meta_class\">";

    foreach($comment_storage as $comment_each)
    {
        echo $cont_main_opening;

                    /** Author **/ 
                    if($bc_author===true){echo $cont_meta_opening;}

                            if($bc_author===true){echo $comment_each->comment_author;}
                            echo ' ';
                            if($bc_date===true){echo get_the_time('j F, Y');}

                    if($bc_date===true){echo $div_closing;}
                    /** Author **/ 

       echo $comment_each->comment_content; 

        echo $div_closing;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'date', 'id', 'content' and 'thumb' are all set to $arguments['author'];

Is this a typo?

If not, this could be your issue.